# check pattern along with length in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the pattern of the date as give (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).
In the below code I want to check anything that is other than yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , if anything else is more or less , it should be false. Is there a better way of checking the pattern so that I don't have to check the length of date separately?

```
public class CheckNumber {

   public static void main(String ...args){
       CheckNumber cn1=new CheckNumber();
       Boolean b=cn1.test("2011-10-12 08:29:56");
       System.out.println(b);
   }




   public static boolean test (String s){
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
       if (matcher.find()){
           return true; 
       } 
       return false; 
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely grasping what you're asking here... Your code seems fine. Don't need a new `CheckNumber` instance if method `test` is static, though. You could check class `SimpleDateFormat` and see if it fits your purpose better.

Comment: What do you mean with, check the date seperately? Seperately to what? Btw. you could just use `matches` function of class String: `dateString.matches(datePattern)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matcher.matches()` instead of `matcher.find()`. That's what it's for : checking if a string completely matches the pattern. You would have easily found this yourself by reading [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

If what you need is to check if it's a valid date, use SimpleDateFormat. To test that the date format parser has completely parsed your string, use the parse method taking a ParsePosition as argument, and check that the position after the parsing is the length of your String.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and javadoc link. will definitely look into javadoc next time.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "better." I would use `SimpleDatePattern` and just try parsing the date: that would both check the format and value ranges (that is, 32nd of January would be ruled out, as well as 30th of February).

E.g.

```
    try {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        format.setLenient(false); // disable heuristics for improper dates
        format.parse(s);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new SimpleDateFormat(yourFormat).parse(date)`. If it returns value the format is OK, if it throws ParseException the format is wrong.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to use the `SimpleDateFormat` solution suggested above and go with a regex. I suggest the following: `^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$`

It is ugly, but it will filter more invalid dates than the one you are currently using. It will also not match strings like: "fooo 2011-10-12 08:29:56 bar" (your code will actually return true for such "dates").